# How can I find matching DNA sequences in two files, using python?

Tags: python, csv, dna-sequence

I have been working on this question for a long time, and I can't seem to get it right. I have tried everything I know and I really need help figuring out what is wrong.

I have two files:
File 1: A list of names and numbers of sequences i.e:

```
name,AGAT,AATG,TATC
Jake,28,42,14
Chris,17,22,19
Anne,36,18,25
```

and File two: A string of DNA
"GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGT..."

The idea is to implement a program that identifies a person based on their DNA. Run through file two, and count the occurrence of the sequences provided in file 1. Return the name if the numbers of occurrence in both files match. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the right 'total' numbers for the 2nd file.

This is what I have so far:

Python:

````
with open(argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:
    csvfile_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvfile_data)          #skip first line
    for row in csvfile_data:
        list_temp = row
        
        # copy elements into a new list
        temp = []
        temp.extend(list_temp)
        
        # remove the first element, because its the name
        name = temp.pop(0)

        # the values attached to the name
        csvlist = temp
        #change strings in list to integers
        csvlist = [int(i) for i in csvlist]

# open dna sequence also
with open(argv[2], 'r') as dnafile:
    dnafile_data = dnafile.read()
    
    #use regular expressions to find each sequence's occurence in the file
    patterns = re.compile(r'AGATC|TTTTTTCT|AATG|TCTAG|GATA|TATC|GAAA|TCTG')
    result = re.findall(patterns, dnafile_data) 
    
    #count each sequence's occurence
    dictionary = Counter(result)
    
    #split the key sand values into a new list 
    dnalist = dictionary.values()
    print(dnalist)
    
if collections.Counter(csvlist) == collections.Counter(dnalist):
    print(name)
else:
    print("No match")
    ```
````

Comment: I think this needs a (short) example of what the input data is to begin to be answerable. I'm also not clear what you expect to happen with overlapping sequences.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for responding, I'm a little new to this.  I'll edit and add an example of the input data to the question.

Comment: Don't know I'm afraid. The second half of it looks like it should work (assuming the sequences don't overlap). `csvlist` will only be for the last line of your first file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the logic behind a simple product recommendation engine such as:

```
def sequence(string):
    count_AGAT = string.count('AGAT')
    count_AATG = string.count('AATG')
    count_TATC = string.count('TATC')
    print(count_AGAT)
    print(count_AATG)
    print(count_TATC)

    data_dna = {'Name': ['01'],
                    'AGAT': [count_AGAT],
                    'AATG': [count_AATG],
                    'TATC': [count_TATC]}
    df_dna = pd.DataFrame(data_dna)
    print(df_dna)
    
sequence('TCATCTAGGAGGCGCGCGTAGGATAAATAATTCAATTAAGATGTCGTTTTGC...')
```

You will get a dataframe output such as:

```
40
31
42
  Name  AGAT  AATG  TATC
0   01    40    31    42
```

Then append the new row to the already available dataframe:

```
df = df.append(df_dna, ignore_index = True)
print(df)
df = df.drop('Name',1)
print(df)
```

The output will be:

```
 Name  AGAT  AATG  TATC
0   Jake    28    42    14
1  Chris    17    22    19
2   Anne    36    18    25
3     01    40    31    42
   AGAT  AATG  TATC
0    28    42    14
1    17    22    19
2    36    18    25
3    40    31    42
```

Save the rows into separate variables:

```
df_jake = df.iloc[0]
df_chris = df.iloc[1]
df_anne = df.iloc[2]
df_sequence = df.iloc[3]
print(df_jake)
```

Get the output:

```
AGAT    28
AATG    42
TATC    14
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

And build a recommendation engine with collaborative filtering (help here: https://realpython.com/build-recommendation-engine-collaborative-filtering/) using the *spatial.distance.euclidean* value:

```
from scipy import spatial
diff_jake = spatial.distance.euclidean(df_sequence, df_jake)
diff_chris = spatial.distance.euclidean(df_sequence, df_chris)
diff_anne = spatial.distance.euclidean(df_sequence, df_anne)
print('Jake: ', diff_jake)
print('Chris: ', diff_chris)
print('Anne: ', diff_anne)
```

The ouput you get, in this example, will be:

```
Jake:  32.38826948140329
Chris:  33.74907406137241
Anne:  21.77154105707724
```

So the dna sequence provided is probably more similar to Anne's.

> you can use scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean to calculate the distance
> between two points. Using it to calculate the distance between the
> ratings of A, B, and D to that of C shows us that in terms of
> distance, the ratings of C are closest to those of B

```
>>> spatial.distance.euclidean(c, a)
2.5
>>> spatial.distance.euclidean(c, b)
0.5
>>> spatial.distance.euclidean(c, d)
2.23606797749979
```

You can also use the cosine distance vector

> To calculate similarity using angle, you need a function that returns
> a higher similarity or smaller distance for a lower angle and a lower
> similarity or larger distance for a higher angle. The cosine of an
> angle is a function that decreases from 1 to -1 as the angle increases
> from 0 to 180.